# How to store and display the customer his payments done on stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment, recurring

I have created a check out with different products with subscription in stripe using **nodejs and react js.**

My question is how i will **store payments and display** them to customers in their dashboard.

Also it is recurring how can i update it **every month**.

Please see if anyone can help me.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how i will store payments and display them to customers in their dashboard.

The [customer portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal) is what you're looking for.

> Also it is recurring how can i update it every month.

If you mean "charge money from the customer every month", that's what the subscription is for. From the questions, it sounds like you're in the early stages of reading the Stripe documentation. Good luck with it!